# message: "You do not have access to the Apex class named 'LoginService '."

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am writing a simple LWC code and facing a problem.
it has a basic JS file and a Apex controller and when I console it, log says 'You do not have access to the Apex class named 'LoginService''. I also checked the permission of this class and it is assigned to the user and Profile. can someone help me out and tell me what can be done or what I am doing wrong.
here is the code

```
    import { LightningElement,track,api } from 'lwc';
import checkLoginDetails from '@salesforce/apex/LoginService.checkLoginDetails';
export default class welcomePage extends LightningElement {
    @track isModalOpen = false;

    openModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = true;
        checkLoginDetails().then(r =>{
            console.log(r);
        }).catch(e =>{
            console.log(e);
        })
    }
}
```

and here is the apex class

```
public with sharing class LoginService {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Boolean checkLoginDetails() {
        system.debug('testtt');
        return true;
    }
}
```

this comes in the screen "Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined throws at [https://lost0ne-developer-edition.ap27.force.com/LWCtest/auraFW/javascript/nj61v-uP3bGswhb-VTdr6Q/aura_prod.js:21:29238"](https://lost0ne-developer-edition.ap27.force.com/LWCtest/auraFW/javascript/nj61v-uP3bGswhb-VTdr6Q/aura_prod.js:21:29238%22)
and the below picture is in the error in the console
[image]

Comment: Recheck again. If this class is added to Apex Classes in the profile. It should not throw this error. Or share screen shot of User's Profile and Apex Classes added to the profile.

Comment: Hey , I checked again having the same problem, i assigned this class to all the profile it's still having the issue.

Comment: Hi, Is the issue fixed? what is the solution?